# invitation chains

Tags: mysql, data-structures

The site `what.cd` uses a type of invitation chain whereby if I invite a friend to the service and they break the rules and loose their account I also loose my account as does the person who invited me and so on.

What is the best way to keep track of this kind of invitation inheritance, Just a table cell linking the user to the user who invited them via their ID or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retain the "inviter" information only on the "invited" model, you have essentially created a singly linked list.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

For the described purpose, the features of such a data structure work reasonably well.

If you think you'll ever need to look at all the people that a person has invited, you may want to keep track of both pieces of information for easier lookup. Alternatively, you could build a table of "invites" that is indexed by both inviter and invitee, which would allow pretty flexible querying.